# Can't run Eclipse project - can't find API database

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk

My code compiles. There is no errors in code. I downloaded full SDK. On run I get this error:

```
Can't find API database; API check not performed
```

And it's in Location: line 1, type Android Lint Problem.

I have no idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it. In manifest I had in uses-sdk minSdkVersion specified but I didn't have targetSdkVersion. After addition of the targetSdkVersion parameter it compiled and ran.

Comment: I have both set:

`android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

Though it shows that error.

Comment: @lama12345 You physically have to have them installed from the SDK manager, if they are not installed, you'll get that error regardless

Answer (score 16):

I have solved it differently. In manifest I had:

```java
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

The problem was that after installation of new Eclipse ADT, in "Android SDK Manager" I didn't have any SDK Platform installed, so I have installed API 19 SDK Platform & Documentation & Sources.

I would also install API 9, but for some reason it is missing in SDK Manager.

Anyway, after this I have edited the `android:minSdkVersion="10"` -> <kbd>SAVE</kbd> -> `again changed to android:minSdkVersion="9"` -> <kbd>SAVE</kbd>

...and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

- go to your `Manifest`
- click on `Uses Sdk`
- change `Min SDK version` to `9` or something else and press `ctrl+s` (save)
- error should disappear now
- change `Min SDK version` back to your original value

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the Package Explorer, right click on the project displaying the Android Lint Problem. Then choose option Android tools- from that point choose Clear Lint Markers

That should remove the error.

Comment: Thanks your a lifesaver!!